# Prioritizing WLAN over LAN connection

Tags: networking, gateway

I'm using my LAN connection to work with a peripheral device, and I would like to use my WLAN connection for internet access. The problem is that Ubuntu considers LAN connection as priority, and doesn't consider to use the WLAN gateway. Network manager doesn't even allow me to delete the LAN gateway.

I have read a lot and known about modifying metrics and other complex methods, but I would like to have a fast and easy way to do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an option that fits perfectly to my needs. In the Network Manager, under the Wired Connection used for just for local purpuses: IPv4 settings--> "Routes" button --> "Use this connection only for resources on its network"